# Powershell calculator script is not working properly

Tags: powershell, variables, calculation

I have created a very simple powershell script to calculate expressions. That is:

```
$expression = read-host -prompt "Enter an expression"
$result = $expression
write-host "The result is $result"
read-host
```

However, when I use it like this:

> Enter an expression: 2+3
>
> The result is 2+3

How can I make the 2nd line calculate the result?

Comment: Parse out the numbers, and the operands separately, then determine the order and apply.  **Have you made any attempt at this in your code so far?**  If so, please [edit] that into your question, so we can see what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6), though be very careful as it will invoke whatever the user enters, not just your simple arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Executing arbitrary code entered by users is very dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did not have any idea how to do it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful for you:

```
 $expression = read-host -prompt "Enter an expression"

# check for dangerous code
if( ($expression -replace '^[0-9\+\-\*\/ ]+$').Length -eq 0 ) {
    try {
        $result = Invoke-Expression $expression
        write-host "The result is $result"
    }
    catch {
        write-host "Syntax error"
    }
}
else {
    write-host "Invalid expression"
}
```